# emacs nw mode, resize split window

Tags: emacs

I'm interested how can I resize split windows in emacs when I'm in console mode?

I opened my file with:

```
emacs myfilename.txt -nw
```

now when I split my window with:

```
C-x 2
```

or

```
C-x 3
```

how can I resize new windows?

Comment: This question could be rephrased as "how to resize emacs window with keyboard commands" or similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Change size of split screen emacs windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4987760/324105)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try <kbd>M-x enlarge-window</kbd> and <kbd>M-x shrink-window</kbd>.

You can specify the number of lines by which to enlarge or shrink with the prefix argument, e.g. to enlarge a window by six lines, type:

<kbd>C-u 6 M-x enlarge-window</kbd>

By default `enlarge-window` is bound to <kbd>C-x ^</kbd>. `shrink-window` is not bound to any shortcut by default, but you can use a negative prefix argument with <kbd>C-x ^</kbd> to get shrinkage.

So you could get the same effect as above by typing:

<kbd>C-u 6 C-x ^</kbd> (enlarge)

<kbd>C-u - 6 C-x ^</kbd> (shrink)

---

A special case is the *horizontal* split where you have additional keyboard shortcuts available for embiggening or shrinking the windows:

<kbd>C-x }</kbd> is bound to `enlarge-window-horizontally`

<kbd>C-x {</kbd> is bound to `shrink-window-horizontally`

Again, you can use prefix arguments to specify the amount (i.e., number of columns) you want to enlarge/shrink the windows with <kbd>C-u</kbd>

Answer (score 33):

If you split window vertically with <kbd>C-x 2</kbd>, use <kbd>C-x ^</kbd> and <kbd>M-x shrink-window</kbd>. If you split horizontally with <kbd>C-x 3</kbd>, use <kbd>C-x {</kbd> and <kbd>C-x }</kbd> to enlarge and shrink.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to shrink-window and enlarge-window, you can also use enlarge-window-horizontally and shrink-window-horizontally.

Personally I bind these like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "A-<down>") 'enlarge-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "A-<up>") 'shrink-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "A-<left>") 'enlarge-window-horizontally)
(global-set-key (kbd "A-<right>") 'shrink-window-horizontally)
```

Then it's very easy to resize -nw window splits using alt-arrow keys.  Also you can just hold the keys down to repeat the command, I find this easier than having to think about how many repeats I want (i.e. using C-u 10 etc).

(more info http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindowResize)

Comment: What does "A" mean? Do you mean "M" (Meta), which is in most cases of modern keyboards the "Alt" key?