# How to use C-x ^ shortcut on German keyboard layout without space key in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

As described here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6315267/772434) The short key `C-x ^` can be used in Emacs to increase the size of a split window.

On my German keyboard layout however, I have to type `Control-X ^ **SPACE**` to get it to work, as the `^` character only appears after hitting the space key.

Is there a way to avoid that and make the command work without having to type SPACE in the end (which is not very elegant)?

Answer (score 0):

I use the standard English layout for Emacs. If I need to type different characters, I use <kbd>C-\</kbd> to switch to a different keyboard layout *in Emacs*.