# How to split a new window horizontally but keep both windows the same width?

Tags: linux, emacs

My window originally was 80 chars wide, and when I `C-x 3` I have to windows both 40 chars wide. Is it possible that when you split the window it automatically widens the whole program so that both windows are 80 chars wide. I'm tired to resizing window every time.

The same applies to `C-x 2` when I need two windows both 24 chars tall.

Note: I wonder how to specify that both widows are 80 chars wide rather than simply balance the width.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315243/emacs-nw-mode-resize-split-window

Comment: @blueberryfields But they only said how to balance windows. How do I specify that both are 80 chars wide?

Comment: The duplicate answer gives all of the details you need - it explains how to adjust to a specific number of lines for each new window (you could do 80-80, or 80-40, or 70-10).

Answer (score 0):

I think @OneZero is asking this: S?he starts with a window that is, say, 80 chars wide, and uses <kbd>C-x 3</kbd> to split it left/right.  That does not increase the *frame* width, so each window now is 40 chars wide.  OneZero wants the *frame* to be widened so that each of the windows is 80 chars wide.

If that is in fact the question then:

- None of the window commands or functions that I am aware of will be of any help.  Whenever they enlarge one window they take the space from other windows.  What you want to do is enlarge the *frame*.
- Command `fit-frame` in library [`fit-frame.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/fit-frame.el) will do what you want, IIUC.  (I bind it to <kbd>C-x C-_</kbd>.)  So <kbd>C-x 3 C-x C-_</kbd>.  (Or you could define a command that does both.)