# How to resize a buffer so it only takes a small part of the screen?

Tags: emacs, emacs23

In Emacs how can I resize a buffer so it only takes a small part of the screen ?

Is there any way ?

I would like to have the src taking 70% of the screen and a file manager in the other 30%

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987760/how-to-change-size-of-split-screen-emacs-windows

Comment: Is it possible to have any way to make it happened when open emacs instead of inputting command after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set width of current window on current frame to ~ 70%:

```
(window-resize nil (- (truncate (* 0.7 (frame-width))) (window-width)) t)
```

The other windows are shrunk automatically. If you want to adjust more than one it gets more difficult.

As command:

```
(defun window-resize-to-70-percent ()
  (interactive)
  (window-resize nil (- (truncate (* 0.7 (frame-width))) (window-width)) t))
```

Comment: should I type it on the mini-buffer ?

Comment: You can type it after `M-:` (`eval-expression`) or you can define it as command (I'll add this to my answer)

Comment: Due to the existence of scroll bars and the like, `window-total-width` seems to be a better function to use

Answer (score 0):

Use separate window-manager frames for individual buffers (by default). Automatically shrink-fit the frames to fit the buffer content.

See [One-On-One Emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OneOnOneEmacs), in particular, libraries [fit-frame.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/fit-frame.el) and [autofit-frame.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/autofit-frame.el).