# Emacs dirtree resize partition

Tags: emacs, resize, split, directory-tree

I have dirtree working with emacs, its very good. The only issue I have with it is that I want to be able to resize the partition between the directory structure on the left and the file I am editing on the right.

I have done some googling around the issue but have not managed to find anything. I am new to emacs so the explanation may need to be in somewhat layman's terms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Change size of split screen emacs windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987760/how-to-change-size-of-split-screen-emacs-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### GUI mode

Hover your mouse over the status line between the two windows, you can drag to resize.

### Terminal or GUI mode

With the point in the dirtree buffer press <kbd>C-{</kbd> to shrink the window or <kbd>C-}</kbd> to expand it.  These commands work one column at a time, if you want to repeat it use <kbd>C-x z</kbd>. i.e.

> <kbd>C-{ C-x z z</kbd>

to shrink by 3 columns.

To change the stepping, use a prefix argument

> <kbd>C-2 C-} C-x z z</kbd>

will expand by 2 columns 3 times.