# Emacs resize vertical windows with mouse

Tags: emacs

I am using Emacs on GUI and I like both vertical and horizontal split windows.

In order to resize horizontal windows, I just grab (with the mouse) the name of the buffer and drag it up and down.

With vertical windows, I can't do that, though. I can't grab the scrollbar, there is no "slider". I know I can use <kbd>C-X {</kbd>, and <kbd>C-X }</kbd>, but these shortcuts are very unnatural, and I'd like to do it with the mouse.

Is there a way I can do that?

[image: Image describing the problem]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Change size of split screen emacs windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987760/how-to-change-size-of-split-screen-emacs-windows)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The status bar between two top windows is draggable.

[image: edited screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! That was hard to reach for, but it's much better now!

Comment: @user996056  it seems if you turn off scroll bar you dont need to go that far to resize. Most of the people turn off scroll bars in emacs `(scroll-bar-mode -1)`

Comment: yeah, except it doesn't work if there are more than two columns!

Comment: @Michael, what do you mean? Both with and without scroll bars, I'm able to grab the place pointed to by the red arrow for each of the column separators. (Using emacs-24.5.1 on win10.)