# Easier way to widen/shrink panel in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Say I have I split-window with `C-x 2` or `C-x 3` and then I want to widen the active panel with `C-x }`. I either have to type this command many times over, or I need to know the exact number of columns I want to widen this panel by and do `M-<N> C-x }`.

But instead what I want is to keep a key pressed down and have the panel expand until I let go. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Change size of split screen emacs windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987760/how-to-change-size-of-split-screen-emacs-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>C-x z</kbd> works to repeat or you can directly make <kbd>C-x }</kbd> repeatable with [repeat-macro-def.el](https://github.com/lewang/le_emacs_libs/blob/master/repeat-macro-def.el).

```
(require 'repeat-macro-def)
(defun-repeatable enlarge-window)
(defun-repeatable enlarge-window-horizontally)
(global-set-key [remap enlarge-window] 'enlarge-window-repeatable)
(global-set-key [remap enlarge-window-horizontally] 'enlarge-window-horizontally-repeatable)
```

Comment: It was a bug I made while refactoring.  Try again, please.

Comment: I don't see any new commits into the github repo, did you remember to push? :)

Comment: Perfect, just what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was answered in [How to change size of split screen emacs windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987760/how-to-change-size-of-split-screen-emacs-windows) (thanks @phils):

Use either `C-x }` or `C-x {` to shrink or widen the panel, then follow it with the repeat command (C-x z to initiate, and keep z pressed for continued repetition).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the numer of columns to move as an argument to <kbd>C-x</kbd> to move as many spaces as you would like. Just hit:

<kbd>M-20</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>{</kbd>

thats while holding alt, enter the number of spaces, then release it.
then hit control x followed by the direction key ( ^, {, }, etc)