# Emacs / Slime / Hard Code Vertical Split Ratio

Tags: emacs, slime

I'm currently in mode: C-x 2

Normally, I don't care much about vertical splitting. However, I'm coding on a 13" display, which makes vertical space rather precious.

I would like some setup where when I do C-x 2, my window is not split 50/50, but rather 70/30 [this way I can send the repl to the bottom portion of the screen, and stll see quite a bit of code.]

C-h a vertical split

brings up:

split-window-vertically, table-split-call-vertically

However, I suspect there is some parameter that changes / controls the split ratio.

What emacs option tells my computer to split 70/30 rather than 50/50?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Change size of split screen emacs windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987760/how-to-change-size-of-split-screen-emacs-windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a prefix argument to tell Emacs how many lines to give each of the two windows.

See: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>
or <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `split-window-below` <kbd>RET</kbd>

> If optional argument SIZE is omitted or nil, both windows get the
> same height, or close to it.  If SIZE is positive, the upper
> (selected) window gets SIZE lines.  If SIZE is negative, the
> lower (new) window gets -SIZE lines.

So you could give the upper window 20 lines and the lower window the remainder with: <kbd>C-u</kbd> `20` <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>
(or <kbd>M-2</kbd><kbd>M-0</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, etc...)

And you could give the lower window 10 lines and the upper window the remainder with: <kbd>C-u</kbd> `-10` <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>
(or <kbd>M--</kbd><kbd>M-1</kbd><kbd>M-0</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, etc...)

See [How to change size of split screen emacs windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987760/how-to-change-size-of-split-screen-emacs-windows/4988206) for lots of ways to modify the size of windows after splitting.

**Edit:**

You can use the following function to do what you want:

```el
(defun my-split-window-below (&optional arg)
  "Split the current window 70/30 rather than 50/50.
A single-digit prefix argument gives the top window arg*10%."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((proportion (* (or arg 7) 0.1)))
    (split-window-below (round (* proportion (window-height))))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c x 2") 'my-split-window-below)
```

The default ratio is 70/30, but you can supply a single-digit prefix argument to specify the size of the top window in 10% increments.

If you bound this command to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> then <kbd>C-9</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> would give the top window 90% and the bottom 10%.

---

**Edit 2:** I ended up using a variation of that as my own <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> binding.  This version defaults to a normal 50/50 split, but provides the same prefix arg functionality of the other function in case I want something different.

```el
(defun my-split-window-below (&optional arg)
  "Split the current window 50/50 by default.
A single-digit prefix argument gives the top window ARG * 10%
of the available lines."
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((proportion (and arg (* arg 0.1)))
         (size (and proportion (round (* proportion (window-height))))))
    (split-window-below size)))
```

Comment: This is almost what I want. Is there a way to set a default -- i.e. not hit C-u # every time? and Have C-x 2 just hit the default? Thanks! [Sorry, switching to emacs from 10 years of vim]