# Dedicated misc buffer in Emacs (autocomplete, function info etc.)

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I have been wondering for a very long time now: **how to get a dedicated misc buffer in Emacs**?

Auto-completion, function descriptions and perhaps documentation all can go there without ending up somewhere unexpected, but instead at a predefined location (a quarter of the screen perhaps?).

Comment: Finally! You could also have, e.g., a different font-size in that dedicated window.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm assuming you mean a dedicated window instead of a dedicated buffer.) If you keep a window open without doing any other window-splitting commands, help/repl buffers will automatically use it. You can change the size of the window as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987760/how-to-change-size-of-split-screen-emacs-windows).

If you want to do be able to do normal window manipulation but have help windows be a certain size, I suggest you investigate `temp-buffer-show-hook`, a hook that is run when temporary buffers (such as help buffers) are shown. I haven't tried it, but it would probably be possible to set it to a function that arranges your window configuration in a particular way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do in [`One On One`](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/OneOnOneEmacs), to define a dedicated `*Help*` frame:

```
;; *Help* frame
(if 1on1-*Help*-frame-flag
    (add-to-list
     'special-display-buffer-names
     (list "*Help*" '1on1-display-*Help*-frame
           (list (cons 'background-color 1on1-help-frame-background)
                 (cons 'mouse-color 1on1-help-frame-mouse+cursor-color)
                 (cons 'cursor-color 1on1-help-frame-mouse+cursor-color)
                 '(height . 40))))
  (setq special-display-buffer-names
        (1on1-remove-if (lambda (elt) (equal "*Help*" (car elt)))
                        special-display-buffer-names)))

(defun 1on1-display-*Help*-frame (buf &optional args)
  "Display *Help* buffer in its own frame.
`special-display-function' is used to do the actual displaying.
BUF and ARGS are the arguments to `special-display-function'."
  (let ((old-ptr-shape (and (boundp 'x-pointer-shape) x-pointer-shape))
        return-window)
    (when (boundp 'x-pointer-xterm) (setq x-pointer-shape x-pointer-xterm))
    (setq return-window (select-window (funcall special-display-function buf args)))
    (raise-frame)
    (setq x-pointer-shape old-ptr-shape)
    return-window))
```

You don't need all of those details (pointer shapes etc.), but that gives you the idea.  The main thing is to put `*Help*` on `special-display-buffer-names`.  That's really all you need to do.

The `1on1-*` variables used for the frame parameters here are pretty obvious.  The `*-remove-if` function is a standard `remove-if`.  The complete code is here: [oneonone.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/oneonone.el).